# Markov Chain with 7 sided polygon and 2 balls

Tags: probability, probability-theory

7 men stand at the vertices of a 7-sided polygon and play a game with 2 balls. Initially (at time 0), the men at vertices A and D hold a ball each. The game ends when any man receives the two balls simultaneously. Before the game ends, and at times 1,2,..., any man holding exactly 1 ball throws it to his clockwise neighbour with probability a (where 0 < a < 1), or to his anti-clockwise neighbour with probability b (1 - a). All such actions are independent. The game can be modelled as a Markov chain by defining state *k*, *k* = 0,1,2,3, as the distance between the 2 balls, measured in number of sides covered by the shorter route around the polygon.


 The diagram is as shown:

[image]


(a) What is the transition probability matrix?
(b) Find all the classes of the Markov chain. Is there any closed class? Is there any recurrent class? State your reasons briefly.
(c) Find the expected number of times the 2 balls are held by two men who are neighbours of each other.


**Attempt:**


I have been working on this problem for hours and still cannot solve it. 

I understand that part (a) requires me to compute the individual probability in the transition matrix. I got

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & a^2 + b^2 + ab & 0 & ab
\\ab & 0 & a^2 + b^2 & ab\\0 & ab & ab & a^2 + b^2\end{bmatrix}$ 

Not sure if I got it correct, as I traced the states based on the diagram shown. The first row is all 0 because we do not want to throw any more balls in that state (game ends).

 For part (b), I believe that there are no closed or recurrent classes as since all states, one way or the other, are accessible from each other...

 For part (c), I am confused with the question, and would really appreciate any help.


Thanks guys!

Comment: You are missing one $ab$ in each of the first two rows. The sum must equal $a^2+2ab+b^2=1$. Also, as the game ends when $k=0$ you may want to not throw any more balls from that state.

Comment: ahh yes, thanks @HagenvonEitzen I forgot to check that the row sums equate to 1

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by when _k_ = 0, we should not throw any more balls from that state? because when _k_ = 0, i thought we can still return to state 0 when the balls move in the same direction

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I get it now, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

*(This answer solves the original version of the question, where $0$ is not an absorbing state. Later on, the transition matrix was modified, and $p(0,0)$ put to $1$. This modification was both unnecessary in the context of the actual mathematical question asked and inappropriate in a Q&A context since an answer was already posted at the time.)*

There is only one communicating class since the path $0\to2\to3\to1\to3\to2\to0$ has positive probability and joins $0$ to $0$ passing through every state. Hence the Markov chain is irreducible. The unique class $\{0,1,2,3\}$ is obviously closed and recurrent. This is not asked but note that some loops $x\to x$ have positive probability hence the Markov chain is also aperiodic.

The Markov chain starts at $3$ and stops when hitting $0$. To compute the expected number of visits of $1$, define $n_x$ as the expected number of visits of $1$ before hitting $0$ starting at $x$. Then the usual one-step recursion reads $n_3=p(3,1)(1+n_1)+p(3,2)n_2+p(3,3)n_3$, $n_2=p(2,2)n_2+p(2,3)n_3$, and $n_1=p(1,1)(1+n_1)+p(1,3)n_3$, where each $p(x,y)$ denotes the transition probability from $x$ to $y$.

This $3\times3$ Cramér system yields $(n_1,n_2,n_3)$, and in particular $n_3$ the expected number of visits of $1$ before hitting $0$ when the Markov chain starts at $3$. (*This value might be $n_3=2/(ab)$.*)

Comment: Thanks @Did for your help. Since the game ends when k = 0, why do we still consider the path from 0 to 0? (the first row in the probability matrix would all consist of 0 then?)

Comment: The new matrix in your question is not a transition matrix. You could keep the old one and simply consider the process before the hitting time $T_0$ of $0$. Or consider that the transition $0\to0$ has probability $1$. Note that anyway, no $p(0,x)$ enters the computation of $n_3$.

Comment: `The first row is all 0` Not anymore, it seems.

Comment: thanks @Did for reminding that the transition probability matrix shouldn't have all 0s in the first row since row sums must equate to one. Regarding part (c), pardon me, but i still do not quite comprehend your methodology...

Comment: OK. Unless you explain what you fail to grasp, I can add nothing to this quite standard approach.

Comment: I understand the recursion bit about N3 = P31(1+N1) + P32(N2) + P33(N3), also for N2 and N1 (by taking conditional expectation). However, I am quite confused about the Cramer system, could you further explain this part please?

Comment: Forget Cramer. You have 3 linear equations with 3 unknowns, in general this allows to compute the 3 unknowns (and here this is so), in particular n3 that you want.

Comment: i see. how about the transition matrix, given that P(0,0) is 1, does that mean that there are 2 classes, {0} and {1,2,3}, instead of {0,1,2,3}?

Comment: See addition to my post.